# Different rulers by file type in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to tell sublime text 2 to display a column 78 ruler in python and javascript and no ruler in HTML, by default?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes! For both a Python and a Javascript file, open it (or just set the syntax for an empty file to `Python` or `Javascript`), then click `Preferences -> Settings – More -> Syntax Specific – User`. Edit that settings file like you would your regular user settings file. Once you're finished, it will look something like this:

```json
{
    "rulers": [
        78
    ]
}
```

Do the same for HTML, but make the `"rulers"` array empty, i.e.:

```json
{
    "rulers": [ ]
}
```

Subsequently, Javascript and Python files will have a ruler at line 78, whereas HTML will display no rulers. Any settings that you can define in your user settings file can be made specific to a syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Close the file and re-open it if it doesn't take effect. Had to do this with my .py files.  Applies for Sublime 3

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me nuts!